# custom marker for vue2-google-maps

Tags: vue.js, vue2-google-maps

I am trying to add my own images for a custom marker in [vue2-google-maps](https://vuejsexamples.com/google-maps-component-for-vue-with-2-way-data-binding/) without success. 
I know this is a bug and when I add an :icon="{url:'../assets/my_image'}" in  tag the marker disappears. 
Has anyone managed to make it work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to load the image in this case, like this:

```
:icon="{ url: require('../../assets/img/marker-a.png')}"
```

An example:

```
<GmapMarker
  v-for="(m, index) in markers"
  :key="index"
  :ref="`marker${index}`"
  :position="m.position"
  :clickable="true"
  :draggable="true"
  :icon="{ url: require('../../assets/img/marker-a.png')}" />
```

Comment: can we add this a class name?

Comment: In my case i had to get rid of require function due I have my images in public laravel directory and this works pretty good

Answer (score 8):

Just in case if you like to scale the size of the custom marker to look better in retina screen:

in `<template>`

```
<GmapMarker
  v-for="(m, index) in markers"
  :key="index"
  :ref="`marker${index}`"
  :position="m.position"
  :clickable="true"
  :draggable="true"
  :icon="markerOptions" />
```

in `script`

```
const mapMarker = require('~/assets/images/layout/map-marker.png');
data() {
  return {
    markerOptions: {
      url: mapMarker,
      size: {width: 60, height: 90, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
      scaledSize: {width: 30, height: 45, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
    },
  };
},
```

Comment: is there any way to add the url dynamically? coming from an API endpoint?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq, just make it `const mapMarker = 'www.lorem.com/path/to/marker/serveing/from/end-point'`

Comment: Can we add this a class name or id?

Comment: were do we find more information about more options of icon prop?

Comment: here, i found it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon