# how to bind a value in require() Vue

Tags: vuejs2

Comin from this question [custom marker for vue2-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51800404/custom-marker-for-vue2-google-maps)

I have markers coming from an endpoint and I am adding markers on `created()` of a `Vue` component

```
<gmap-marker :key="i" v-for="(m,i) in markers" :position="m.position" :clickable="true" @click="toggleInfoWindow(m,i)" :icon="{ url: require('./online.png') }"></gmap-marker>
```

`m` has such value

```
{
 infoText: "synno-hlcna",
 position: {
  lat: 53.3600171,
  lng: -6.2630125
 },
 status: "online"
}
```

How I can use `m.status` value in `require()`.

I have tried to add full `{ url: require('./online.png') }` through `m.url` as well as just `require(m.url)` and Url was './online.png', It gave me an error as

module not found `./online.png`

I want to change the peg colour on the base of status. I have to pngs, online/offline according to `m`.

How is that possible to bind value in require('./{status}.png') so it may work?

I have tried this way as well

:icon=`{ url: require('./${m.status}.png') }`

UPDATE:
I tried to use v-bind such as

```
<gmap-marker :key="i" v-for="(m,i) in markers" :position="m.position" :clickable="true" @click="toggleInfoWindow(m,i)" v-bind:icon="{ url: require(m.status) }"></gmap-marker>
```

its giving error as `Cannot find module './online.png'` How can we make it work ? it works only if I put `./online.png` by myself.

Comment: in what directory is your vue component located, and where is the png file?

Comment: maps directory. and png is also in maps directory.